# HttpsURLConnection memory leak

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection, leakcanary

Using LeakCanary, I found a memory leak that made a log like this.

```
HttpsURLConnection$NoPreloadHolder.defaultHostnameVerifier -> 
MainActivity$16.this$0 -> 
MainActivity
```

The only part on my code that mention `HttpsUrlConnection` is this.

```
static SSLContext sc;
private void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try{
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }};

        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSSL err: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If I remember correctly, that code is for making Volley accept https requests. I saw some post the says I need to close `URLConnection` but `HttpsURLConnection` doesn't have a method for closing it. Making `SSlContext` to `static` didn't change anything.

I call `handleSSLHandshake()` on `onCreate()` of MainActivity.

This is the previous `handleSSLHandshake()` method.

```
private void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try{
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSSL err: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `HttpsUrlConnection` by using [`disconnect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect()) method.

Comment: how to I do that on my case? because I didn't initialize `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

delete modifier static before SSLContext sc.

Comment: At first, it was really not static. It was previously inside handleSSLHandshake and it still cause memory leak

Comment: Did you mean static SSLContext sc; is not static?

Comment: Yes. It was previously not static and it's `SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");`.

Comment: Can you modify your question?Post your leak activityis whole code.

Comment: it got 3k lines of code. Do I really need to post it all?

Comment: Maybe you can add a link for it.

Comment: It's on our local gitlab. And it's set to internal